# Add hover image (CSS) to ASP.NET link button in a DataPager

Tags: asp.net

I add hover images to .Net LinkButtons using the following method:

```
.rollover a 
{
  background-image:url(/images/shoppingcart/butpill_continue.gif);
}

.rollover a:hover 
{
  background-image:url(/images/shoppingcart/butpill_continue_over.gif);
}

<div class="rollover">
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnContinue" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

This works fine with regular link buttons.

I need to add this to my next/previous buttons in a DataPager.  I tried setting the ButtonType to "Link" and applying the ButtonCssClass="rollover" but this doesn't work.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your css to

```
a.rollover { background-image:url(/images/shoppingcart/butpill_continue.gif); }

a.rollover:hover { background-image:url(/images/shoppingcart/butpill_continue_over.gif); }
```

Or just

```
.rollover { background-image:url(/images/shoppingcart/butpill_continue.gif); }

.rollover:hover { background-image:url(/images/shoppingcart/butpill_continue_over.gif); }
```

You'll also have to change your other images to something like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnContinue" runat="server" CssClass="rollover" />
```